# Worksheet_Change target range is too slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro used to change formula. The problem is the although the macro works it makes updating the Excel sheet rather laggy. Any suggestion?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Columns.Count < Me.Columns.Count Then
        If Target.Column = 4 Then
            If Target.Row >= 49 And Target.Row <= 178 Then
                Dim r As Integer
                For r = 49 To 178
                    'AD = 30
                    Dim MatType As String
                    MatType = Cells(r, 4).Value
                    If MatType = "" Then
                        Cells(r, 30).Value = "0"
                    Else
                        MatType = LCase(MatType)
                        'Plechy
                        'Trubky
                        'Jine
                        If MatType = "pzs" Or MatType = "pzt" Or MatType = "Tahokov" Then
                            Cells(r, 30).Value = "=(I" & r & " * J" & r & "*L" & r & ") * 2/1000000"
                        ElseIf MatType = "jac" Or MatType = "jao" Or MatType = "tr" Or MatType = "u" Or MatType = "kr" Or MatType = "L" Or MatType = "op" Or MatType = "Trubky_spec" Then
                            Cells(r, 30).Value = "=(F" & r & "*I" & r & "*L" & r & ")/1000000"
                        Else
                            Cells(r, 30).Value = "0"
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Range("D49:D178"), Target) Then` You can drop two if statements since it looks like you are just creating the bounds of a range. You can also remove another `If` by just using replace to swap `""` for `"0"`

Comment: use variant arrays, or only look at the cell that changed and not all of them.

Comment: Are the changes being drop in, in mass, or are they being changed one by one?

Comment: They being changed ony by one.

Comment: In addition to the important other comments about Intersect, arrays, and single vs mass: 1) `If MatType = "" Then` just clutters the code and would be handled the same by the If/ElseIf/Else block below; 2) Curious... Is there a reason you are doing this in VBA and not with a formula?

Comment: You're changing values in a function that gets triggered every time a value gets changed.  It's a recursive function and that can be really bad.  I'd set up a Global boolean ("bUpdating = False") that gets checked at the start of your function and only allows the function to continue if it's false, otherwise Exit Sub.  Set the boolean to True if it passes that check and continue your function, then once your function completes set it back to False.  This will prevent the recursion from occuring.

Comment: @FrankBall `Application.EnableEvents = False` should be handling that already.

Comment: @Mark Balhouf - Nice catch, It's a command that I rarely use, since it can stop behavior that you might otherwise want to run.  I prefer to use a Global variable to handle these kind of situations, since it's puts my code in complete control and doesn't rely on assumptions about what does and doesn't happen.  It's a quick and easy way to stop events from firing, but it also can cause some substantial issues.

Answer (score 2):

this will only loop those that change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo safeout
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("D49:D178"), Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim rngCell As Range
        For Each rngCell In rng
            Dim r As Long
            r = rngCell.Row
            'AD = 30
            Dim MatType As String
            MatType = LCase$(rngCell.Value)                      
            'Plechy
            'Trubky
            'Jine
            Select Case MatType
                Case "pzs", "pzt", "Tahokov"
                    Cells(r, 30).Value = CDbl(Cells(r, "I")) * Cells(r, "J") * Cells(r, "L") * 2 / 1000000
                Case "jac", "jao", "tr", "u", "kr", "L", "op", "Trubky_spec"
                    Cells(r, 30).Value = CDbl(Cells(r, "I")) * Cells(r, "F") * Cells(r, "L") / 1000000
                Case Else
                    Cells(r, 30).Value = 0
            End Select
        Next
    End If
safeout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```